# How can you get rid of the 'file name' title and size of the download control?

Tags: xpages

The download control is displaying the words "File Name" above the attachment.  Is there anyway to get rid of that?

Also, despite the fact that I set the DisplaySize to false, it's still showing up.  Any ideas on that?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to all properties tab and set properties "display..." and "fileName..." depending on what you want to show.

[image]

In your case you'd set `displaySize` to false and `fileNameTitle` to a space character.

Setting that there is no size column anymore and file name titel is empty.

Comment: Thanks!  I was a bit reluctant to play with the 'fileNameTitle' as I thought it had to do with the name of the file.  So I put in a space and it clear it.  Appreciate the pointer!

Comment: Could you get rid of the size column too? It works for me with just setting displaySize to false.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get rid of the size column as well.  Thanks.